# Huge discrepancy between file Mtimes from Rust and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, rust, time, unix-timestamp, filemtime

I've stumbled across a very unexpected issue, which is that I'm trying to download a file from a NodeJS server from Rust only if the destination file is older than the source. The mtime for the Source file is given by NodeJS using the

```js
let mtime = await source.stat()
  .then(stat => stat.mtime.getTime());
```

which is serialised into JSON along with some other data, and deserialised by Serde on the other end. Note that this value is and stays an integer, and has no consideration for timezones etc.

The receiving end looks like this:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Event {
  // ..
  mtime: u64
}
// ..
async fn download(event: Event) {
  if let Ok(meta) = dest.metadata().await {
    let source_mtime = event.mtime.duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)?.as_millis();
    let dest_mtime = meta.modified()?.duration_since(UNIX_EPOCH)?.as_millis();

    if source_mtime > dest_mtime {
      // download
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I print out the two mtime values in Rust (`source_mtime`, `dest_mtime`), the two values are off by 1 686 675 098 702 which seems a bit much for files which were created within the same week. I then repeated the experiment after `touch`ing the source file, and ensuring the mtime was updated too, to find the same amount of discrepancy.

I'm aware of system time drift, and that this may be a source of errors, but to be off by a quadrillion seems a bit excessive. (That's a difference of ~53 years)

If anyone has any insight as to what causes this and/or whether this is just a silly mistake on my end, I'd love to hear it.

Best,
JCake

### Edit:

As per @isaactfa's comment, below is a endianness test:

```
[
  <Buffer 96 0d 2d 3a 89 01 00 00>,
  <Buffer 2b 4c f1 74 12 03 00 00>,
  <Buffer 00 00 01 89 3a 2d 0d 96>,
  <Buffer 00 00 03 12 74 f1 4c 2b>
]
```

As you can see, the values are not remotely similar, even with the byte-order swapped.

A good suggestion, but no cigar...

Comment: Have you made sure that endianness is the same on both ends?

Comment: both processes are running on the same device/os etc. I hadn't tested it explicitely but I don't see how that could possibly come up in this scenario

Comment: 53 years is awfully close to the current EPOCH time (which is `1_688_914_009_000` at the time of writing this comment). I think one of your two methods returns zero, or something similar. Please provide some examples for the actual times your programs produce, not just how far they are apart.

Comment: Note that `00 00 01 89 3a 2d 0d 96` is `1688898178454`, which is `Sunday, July 9, 2023 10:22:58.454 AM`. `00 00 03 12 74 f1 4c 2b`, however, means nothing. Which program is producing the `00 00 03 12 74 f1 4c 2b`?

Comment: The Rust program is producing the latter value. Interestingly however, the latter value is precisely twice what it should be. I'll do some more digging and keep you guys posted

Comment: Curious: you have `Event::mtime` as a `u64` but you're calling `.duration_since()` like its a `SystemTime`/`Instant`. Is there a step missing?

Comment: Good catch, @kmdreko. J-Cake, you might have to provide a full [MRE] for us to help you further.